# How can the AVERAGEIFS function be translated into MATLAB?

Tags: excel, matlab, if-statement, matrix, average

I am working at moving my data over from Excel to Matlab. I have some data that I want to average based on multiple criteria. I can accomplish this by looping, but want to do it with matrix operations only, if possible.

Thus far, I have managed to do so with a single criterion, using accumarray as follows:

```
data=[
    1 3
    1 3
    1 3
    2 3
    2 6
    2 9];

accumarray(data(:,1),data(:,2))./accumarray(data(:,1),1);
```

Which returns:

```
3
6
```

Corresponding to the averages of items `1` and `2`, respectively. I have at least three other columns that I need to include in this averaging but don't know how I can add that in. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For your single column, you don't need to call `accumarray` twice, you can provide a function handle to `mean` as the fourth input

```
mu = accumarray(data(:,1), data(:,2), [], @mean);
```

For multiple columns, you can use the *row indices* as the second input to `accumarray` and then use those from within the anonymous function to access the rows of your data to operate on.

```
data = [1  3  5
        1  3  10
        1  3  8
        2  3  7
        2  6  9
        2  9  12];

tmp = accumarray(data(:,1), 1:size(data, 1), [], @(rows){mean(data(rows,2:end), 1)});
means = cat(1, tmp{:});
%   3.0000   7.6667
%   6.0000   9.3333
```